# PCA for 3D Lidar data

Tags: pca, eigenvalues, julia

I'm trying to work with Lidar data to classify road. I'm wondering how to use pca (or something else?) to identify if region has connectivity > threshold then label the region to be road? Would Eigen Vectors be helpful in determining direction of road?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How would you do it without PCA?

Comment: 'connectivity > threshold' what is connectivity?

Comment: What sort of lidar data do you have? Do you know that there is a road on an image and wish to compute some specific value for it, like recognize the edge. Or are you looking for some sort of image recognition solution (eg a program that classifies whether something on a lidar image is a road or not)?